# django custom property to return filtered field

Tags: python, django, django-models

In a django app, with an existing database, I've used `inspectdb` to build a model:

```
  class Sensorparser(models.Model):
      """ a read-only implemenation to access the MeshliumDB """
      id_wasp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
      id_secret = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
      frame_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
      frame_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
      sensor = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
      value = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
      timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
      raw = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
      parser_type = models.IntegerField()

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          return

      def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
          return

      class Meta:
          managed = False
          db_table = 'sensorParser'
```

I added the `save` and `delete` methods because this should be a read-only model.

One of the fields is `sensor` which defines strings for different, well, "sensors" (e.g. BAT, ANE, etc.). I would like to have a property like this:

```
@property
def battery()
    return self.sensor.objects.filter(sensor='BAT')
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers):

```
class BatteryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(BatteryManager, self).get_queryset().filter(sensor='BAT')

class Sensorparser(models.Model):
    batteries = BatteryManager()
    # etc
```

And use it like this:

```
batteries = Sensorparser.batteries.all()
```

Comment: And to generalize it a bit more? The following doesn't work:  ` class SensorManager(models.Manager):
  
      def get_queryset(self, sensor):
          return super(SensorManager, self).get_queryset().filter(sensor=sensor)
  
`

Comment: Yes it doesn't work. You can create many managers for different sensor types and use it. Or if you has many sensor types you can write custom method in manager: `class SensorparserManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_by_sensor(self, sensor):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(sensor=sensor)

class Sensorparser(models.Model):
    objects = SensorparserManager()` And use it like this `Sensorparser.objects.filter_by_sensor('BAT')`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
def _get_battery(self):
    return self.sensor.objects.filter(sensor='BAT')
battery = property(_get_battery)
```